# jumper pins on arduino board

Tags: soldering, jumper

I have an arduino board but the jumper pins are seperate from the board itself. 

**Q:** How should I attach this? solder? glue?
I dont want to make a mess and have the solder drops touch each other pins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solder with one hand?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145916/how-to-solder-with-one-hand)

Comment: The solder mask will prevent bridges unless excessive amounts of solder are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard Soldering techniques should be used. If you need, get some prototype/vero/strip board and practice first. As @ignacio has mentioned, the solder mask will help as long as you don't glob on the solder. Most importantly, use flux and you'll be fine.

Comment: @tq: You don't "need" it per se; it's already on the board. It's the green layer covering most of the board, leaving only the metal intended to connect to parts exposed.

Comment: As @Passerby mentioned you should be fine. Make sure you use fine rosin cored solder. You can hot glue the very ends of the jumpers to hold it steady and perpendicular while you solder if you need to.

Comment: @BenG "hot glue" as in Glue Gun Stick?

Comment: Yep. Though Davids use of blutack is a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

As an experienced solderer. I recommend using blutack to adhere it to the board and the solder 1 pin in. Once this is done, you can reapply heat to that pin to align it. Continue with others